# Xstream List - Duplicate field

Tags: java, json, xstream

I have a problem with XStream. I have a java class called simplePerson as follows:

```
public class SimplePerson {

@XStreamAlias("name")
private String name;


private List<String> cars;
```

I am using it to convert it to json using:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver(){
        public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer writer) {
            return new JsonWriter(writer);
        }
    });

xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);

xstream.toXML(person)
```

Using it I get the following json: 
{"simpleperson": {
  "name": "joe",
  "cars": ["Jag", "BMW"] }}

When I use the same json to convert it back to an object using xstream.fromXML(json), I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: Duplicate field cars

I cant figure out what is the problem. I am using the same exact json that Xstream gave as output. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you need to add Implicit collection. like.

```
xstream.addImplicitCollection(SimplePerson.class, "cars");
```

Comment: FYI, I had the exact same problem and this solution worked for me.

Comment: edit: One more update, for Xstream 1.2.2 I had to do this: xstream.addImplicitCollection(SimplePerson.class, "cars", String.class);